# How to handle different datatype options when compiling?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opengl

How should i handle multiple datatype possibilities in my code?

I want it to be possible to compile using double or float type, here is the code i use at the moment:

```
#define USE_FLOAT_PRECISION

...

#ifdef USE_FLOAT_PRECISION
    typedef float DATATYPE;
    #define GL_DATATYPE GL_FLOAT
#else
    typedef double DATATYPE;
    #define GL_DATATYPE GL_DOUBLE
#endif

...

DATATYPE somevar;
...
for(...){
    for(...){
        ...
        somevar *= (DATATYPE)1.02; // is this good?
        ...
    }
}

...

glVertexPointer(3, GL_DATATYPE, ... // can this be done better?

...
```

This works just fine, but i feel there is something bad with casting by (DATATYPE) for every place i use it, also looks ugly too, it gets annoying to paste that for every place. Any other solution?

**Edit:** the reason im concerned about the casting to `(DATATYPE)` is because i need to express the float value with double precision in my code, but then convert it to (float) later, so im afraid converting from double to float would cause some problems. Also im not sure if its efficient, ive heard that static_cast is faster or something. But im not sure why should i use it and should i use it here at all.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how I've seen it done in the past. Only difference being the use of a function-style macro for access: DATATYPE_CREATE( 0.5 ). This allows you to implement more than just a cast for your float type. E.g. it could be a class on a platform with no hardware floating point.

Comment: sounds like a job for templates, no?

Comment: The compiler ought to convert constants to floats at compile time. Also, you may need extra macros for dealing with sprintf type stuff, to differentiate between %f and %Lf

Comment: @Hybrid, %f works fine for doubles and floats, so far no problems with that.

Comment: Regarding your worries about performance, I suggest mocking up your alternatives, and comparing the assembler.

Comment: Can you show us an OpenGL implementation that uses doubles internally?

Comment: @genpfault, i do in my program, since i do complex float calculations, and i think converting those into floats just for opengl would be a lot slower, than just directly using doubles instead. it works, i cant see much performance loss either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pasting this code in everywhere, consider putting it in a header that you can just include where you need it.

Your approach above will work and is one of several approaches to achieve what you want.

Other approaches might involve using templates which may simplify your code a little and provide greater flexibility.

Comment: what do you mean by header? that macro? of course. that wasnt what i meant with "pasting this code everywhere", i meant that "(DATATYPE)" before every possible float value i use. The reason why im concerned about that is that i need to express the float with double type and then convert it to float again.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 has user defined literals which can be used to simplify the cast:

```
DATATYPE operator "" _dt(long double x) {
  return x;
}

somevar *= 1.02_dt;
```

Comment: niiiice, too bad my compiler doesnt support that :/ also im not sure how efficient it is, does it work like a function call every time i use 1.02_dt in my code? also read my edits, how about static_cast ? is that better?

Comment: @Rookie It will be inlined with no overhead - same as `(DATATYPE)` and `static_cast<DATATYPE>`. `static_cast` is just a more specific version of C-style casts - identical performance, yet safer.